# How to create List Item in my SharePoint Site List from excel sheet?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, caml-query

I have already created list in my SharePoint I want to create the item in this list from Excel Sheet. How can i do this? Is any java script or any other?
I want to import all the record to my SharePoint List from Excel Sheet.I want to give one button on my share point site list. When user click on that button, item is created to my share point List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the question correctly, you wish to create items in a list based on data in an excel spreadsheet.

A fast way of doing this is to create a Data Sheet view of the list, open this in Internet Explorer (from my experience, Google Chrome won't work for this), then you can copy and paste the contents of this file directly into the cells in the Data Sheet view.

Depending on how much data you are copying, you may need to wait for some time for it all to be committed to the list.

Edit: One comment on using Data Sheet view - don't use this view to create new columns, as the internal name of the column will not match the name you give it - this can make workflows challenging in the future.

Comment: Is any programming way so user does not need to copy past?Thanks for Reply.

Comment: An alternative method would be to use PowerShell to read the data from the spreadsheet, and then create items in the newly created list.

Answer (score 1):

There are two formats to working with a list in a browser. Standard and Quick edit. Quick edit is similar to a spread sheet so you can make bulk edits.

Pasting data into the Quick Edit view is rather straight forward you just need to have the column order and formats in excel matching the ones you have in SharePoint (text=text, dates=dates, etc.) Also you need to conceder any required columns you have in SharePoint as they need to have data in order to go to the next line if your pasting in multiple rows. Next be sure you select the blank first cell at the bottom of your quick edit view by clicking on it once and not twice or it will try to paste your contents into one cell instead of pasting in the new row of cells. (hopefully that made sense)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft add in works with Excel 2007 to allow you to synchronize data in a table with a list on a SharePoint site.

This was created for SP 2007 but work with SP 2010 and SP 2013 (on prem & online too).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=9345

Answer (score 1):

if you are using on-premise you can use powershell to do this task. below are steps.

1. first convert your excel sheet to CSV file.

   2. you can use below code

## Setup the correct modules for SharePoint Manipulation

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null ) 
{ 
   Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
} 
$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"


#Open SharePoint List 
$SPServer=http://LAB-SPS1 
$SPAppList="/Lists/Application List/" 
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $SPServer 
$spData = $spWeb.GetList($SPAppList)

$InvFile="appinvent.csv" 
# Get Data from Inventory CSV File 
$FileExists = (Test-Path $InvFile -PathType Leaf) 
if ($FileExists) { 
   "Loading $InvFile for processing…" 
   $tblData = Import-CSV $InvFile 
} else { 
   "$InvFile not found – stopping import!" 
   exit 
}

# Loop through Applications add each one to SharePoint

"Uploading data to SharePoint…."

foreach ($row in $tblData) 
{ 
   "Adding entry for "+$row."Application Name".ToString() 
   $spItem = $spData.AddItem() 
   $spItem["Application Name"] = $row."Application Name".ToString() 
   $spItem["Application Vendor"] = $row."Application Vendor".ToString() 
   $spItem["Application Version"] = $row."Application Version".ToString() 
   $spItem["Install Count"] = $row."Install Count".ToString() 
   $spItem.Update() 
}

"—————" 
"Upload Complete"

$spWeb.Dispose()

for more reference you can use below link
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stuffstevesays/2013/06/06/populating-a-sharepoint-list-using-powershell/

Comment: I was just coming back to add that to my answer above! Nice job!

Comment: if it is solve you problem please upvote and mark as answer, so it can be helpful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Import a Spreadsheet as an App' in SP 2013.  More details here: https://sharepoint.protiviti.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=183

Comment: Can i Import Excel sheet to my Exiting SharePoint List  Using this approach ?

Comment: No, but you can export the existing list items into excel, merge it and then use this or use quick edit view (it will only work in IE).